# Perl CGI script served by IIS fails to start with HTTP-502 error but works if tried again

Tags: perl, iis-7, cgi

I have been searching a long time for a solution to this problem:

a Perl CGI script served by an IIS7 web server sometimes fails with a HTTP-502 error: "HTTP Error 502.2 – Bad Gateway CGI application did not return a complete set of HTTP headers"

Usually this error occurs if this script has not been called for a longer time, typically several hours. If the user retries the action starting this script it will work.
I think the IIS returns the HTTP-502.2 error because the Perl interpreter had printed an error message to STDERR. My guess is that the current working directory is sometimes not set correctly (not to the physical path corresponding to the virtual path of the request), so the Perl interpreter can't find the script.

On the IIS the message to STDERR gets lost. Using
`CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser)`
does not help either; it never prints an error message, backing my theory of the Perl interpreter not finding the script.
I have seen an Apache server running on Windows showing the same behaviour: after a long pause there is one failure, and retrying the script works flawlessly.
Possibly, a shell is used internally to run the Perl interpreter.

The IIS setup for the "perl" folder treats the folder as an application.
The handler mapping maps "*.pl" files to

`c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "%s" %s`

Is there any setting (Windows or IIS) I have to add to enforce the correct environment and current working directory?

Comment: What platform of perl you installed? Like stawberry perl, or active perl

Comment: ActiveStatePerl 5.8.8

Answer (score 0):

Another trick for run the PERL cgi from IIS.

`First click -> Handler Mappings`

`Then right side action box click -> Add module Mapping`

`Request Path -> *.pl`

`Module -> IsapiModule`

`Executable -> Activeperl\bin\PerlEx30.dll`

`Name -> perl (anything)`

`Request Restrictions -> Mapping -> file or folder, verbs -> all verbs ,
access -> Execute`
then click OK

Then you will show the name perl into the Add module mapping

Then the left side corner

`Right click on the Sites and click Add web Site`

`site name -> perl.com (anything)`

`Physical path -> select the folder which is contain the perl cgi scripts`

`Host name -> perl.com`
 then click ok

Then the below is important for run CGI

`c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`

open the hosts file 
then add the `host name-> into the hosts file below the ::1
like my Host name in iis is perl.com so i added 127.0.0.1 perl.com`
Then save it.

Then run the perl cgi on browser like `perl.com/file.pl`

Comment: Dear Hussain,thank you for your reply. I now had access to the server.

Comment: I found the problem to be caused by the Perl intepreter writing to STDERR as I guessed - but it was a warning: 

`utf8 "\xFF" does not map to Unicode...`

The warning came up when the Perl program read a config file containing 8 bit characters from the Latin-1 character set while expecting UTF-8.

There are 2 machines forming a cluster with a load balancer - and only on one machine the config file contained Latin-1 characters. Maybe it's fixed now.

Comment: @elwood Sorry for saying this I don't faced this kine of problem,So  dont' have any idea. When i'll get the idea, i'll post.